# C++ - Array manipulation without copy constructors or assignment operator

Tags: c++

## Problem

Can arrays of objects be manipulated (sorted, sliced, reversed, e.t.c.) without using its objects constructors/ assignment operators to change their indexes in the array?

## Context

The issue here is the copying. For objects that privately use a copy constructor/ assignment operator or don't use such features (`= delete`), how does one effectively manipulate these objects' stores within an array?

For example, this would be an obvious way to swap two indexes in an array

```
template <typename type>
void swap(type* array, const size_t indexA, const size_t indexB) {
      type temp = array[indexA]; // Wouldn't work without a copy constructor.

      array[indexA] = array[indexB]; // Wouldn't work without a copy assignment operator.
      array[indexB] = temp;
}
```

This method creates a temporary copy of the index to be swapped (using the object's constructor) and then swaps the two locations (using the object's assignment operator).

But what if the object didn't allow explicit use of these features (the constructor & and assignment operator)? So I decided to try my hand at a custom implementation that met the demands of this problem and share it here to see if there's anything wrong with it (a lot of comments in the code, I know).

```
#include <iostream> // For information logging to the console.
#include <stdlib.h> // `EXIT_SUCCESS`, `free`, `malloc`, and `realloc`.
#include <string.h> // Contains functions for manipulating byte strings,
                    // but can these functions be re-purposed for pointers as well?

/* Generic object with a count index that increments on its instantiation.
    This is the object that we'll be working with.
*/
class Object {
    private:
        static unsigned char total;
        const unsigned char value; // The object's index.

    public:
        Object(void) : value{++Object::total} {}
        constexpr Object(Object&&) = delete; // No copy/ move constructors.
        constexpr Object(const Object&) = delete;

        Object& operator =(Object&&) const noexcept = delete; // No copy/ move assignment operators.
        Object& operator =(const Object&) const noexcept = delete;

        // Allow printing to the console by the `std::cout` output stream object.
        friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& stream, Object& object) { stream << object.toString(); return stream; }

        // Allow the object be viewed as a byte string.
        const char* toString(void) noexcept {
            static char string[4] {'0', '0', '0', '\0'}; // I know it's static but I'm not creating THAT many `Object` objects.
            unsigned char value = this -> value;

            *(string + 2) = (value % 10u) + 48u; value /= 10u;
            *(string + 1) = (value % 10u) + 48u; value /= 10u;
            *string = (value % 10u) + 48u;

            return (const char*) string;
        }
};
unsigned char Object::total = 0u;

/* Store of `Object` objects (our custom array). */
class ObjectArray {
    private:
        size_t length;
        Object *value;

    public:
        constexpr ObjectArray(void) : length{0u}, value{(Object*) ::malloc(0u)} {}
        ~ObjectArray(void) {
            ::free(this -> value);
            ::free((char*) ObjectArray::toString()); // Free the heap-allocated value in the static local variable;
                                                     // not clean but will do for now.
        }

        // Allow printing to the console by the `std::cout` output stream object.
        friend inline std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& stream, const ObjectArray& array) { stream << array.toString(); return stream; }

        Object& operator [](size_t index) const noexcept { return *(this -> value + index);  }
        template <typename type> operator type*(void) const noexcept { return (type*) ObjectArray::toString(); }

        // Empty the array.
        void free(void) noexcept { ::free(this -> value); this -> length = 0u; this -> value = (Object*) ::malloc(0u); }

        // Remove an element from the array (we don't need to shrink the heap space occupied by the array for this test).
        void pop(void) noexcept { --this -> length; }

        // Add a referenced object into the array (without the copy/ move constructors).
        void push(Object& object) noexcept {
            ObjectArray::resize(this -> length + 1u);
            ::memmove(this -> value + (this -> length - 1u), &object, sizeof(Object));
        }

        // Add a temporary object into the array (without the copy/ move constructors).
        void push(Object&& object) noexcept { ObjectArray::push((Object&) object); }

        // Resize the array.
        //     Newly created elements should have a default value somehow, that's where `memset` came in but is this undefined behavior?
        //     We default the elements to `NULL` or `0` rather than leaving the values somewhat random e.g.: `int()`.
        void resize(const size_t length) noexcept {
            if (length) {
                this -> value = (Object*) ::realloc(this -> value, length * sizeof(Object));
                if (length > this -> length) ::memset(this -> value + (this -> length), 0x0, length - (this -> length));
                this -> length = length;
            } else ObjectArray::free();
        }

        // Allow the object be viewed as a byte string.
        const char* toString(void) const noexcept {
            size_t length = 0u;
            static char *string = NULL; // Re-use the same string for each invocation of this method.

            ::free(string);
            string = (char*) ::malloc((((this -> length * 3u) + (this -> length * 2u) + (3u)) - (this -> length ? 2u : 0u)) * sizeof(char));

            // Add each element`s string representation to the main byte string.
            for (size_t iterator = 0u; iterator ^ (this -> length); ++iterator) {
                const char *objectString = (this -> value + iterator) -> toString();

                *(string + ++length) = *objectString;
                *(string + ++length) = *(objectString + 1);
                *(string + ++length) = *(objectString + 2);

                // Add the delimiters i.e.: `", "`.
                if (iterator < this -> length - 1u) { *(string + ++length) = ','; *(string + ++length) = ' '; }
            }

            *string = '[';
            *(string + ++length) = ']';
            *(string + ++length) = '\0';

            return (const char*) string;
        }
};

/* Main: For testing only... */
int main(void) {
    ObjectArray array; // -> []
    Object object; // -> 001

    // `std::cout` the `array` to view its contents.
    array.push(object); // Pushes without copying the referred object -> [001]
    array.push(Object()); // Pushes without copying the temporary object -> [001, 002]
    array.push(object); // -> [001, 002, 001]
    array.pop(); // For testing only... -> [001, 002]
    array.push(Object()); // -> [001, 002, 003]
    array.push(Object()); // -> [001, 002, 003, 004]
    array.resize(7u); // On resize (which it had done for the previous operations), the following elements are zeroed (by default) -> [001, 002, 003, 004, 000, 000, 000]

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This attempt compiles and works for me so far, but I’d like to see everyone’s input:

- Is this a reasonable approach to manipulating an array of objects without deferring to the object's member functions?
- How would you approach the same problem?

Comment: No, pretty much all of it has undefined behavior. You are never creating objects in the malloc'ed storage. What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve here? Do you want a `std::vector` for non-movable types?

Comment: More or less, I want to see how to an `std::vector` for non-movable types will be implemented. By non-movable I'm guessing it can't be copied (via assignment or constructor)?

Comment: I'm not trying to create objects within the array itself, rather just emplace already-created objects into the array without creating temporary copies or explicitly copying the object into the array.

Comment: The language does not allow that at all. The only way you are allowed to do this is by directly constructing the objects in-place in the array/vector. The whole point of a non-movable type (one without copy or move constructor or assignment operator) is that it cannot be moved from one location to another.

Comment: If you need a container with non-movable types, you can use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>>` or `std::deque<Object>` or `std::list<Object>`, each with the `emplace_back` and `pop_back` methods. The former uses an indirection through the smart pointer for each element, the latter two do not store elements continuously.

Comment: I'm not too convinced. The custom container I used in the question and the C++ features you presented (`std::vector`, `std::deque`, and `std::list`) seems to work well with the `Object` type (which I believe is non-movable), and I don't see why the behavior of my implementation is undefined,.. yet.

Comment: I am writing comments because I am still not sure what specifically you want to know. If your question is simply whether the shown program is well-behaved I can write an answer for that, but it is still not clear to me what practical problem you are trying to solve, so I won't be able to answer to that.

Comment: @walnut That's exactly it, I want to know if the program above is well-behaved: "Is this a reasonable approach to manipulating an array of objects without deferring to the object's member functions?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program has undefined behavior starting with at least the first `push` operation.

In particular `push` calls `resize` which performs the action

```
this -> value + (this -> length)
```

`this->value` is a pointer returned from `realloc`, which returns a pointer to *allocated storage* without creating objects in it. You are not using any placement-`new` on this storage location that would create any object. Therefore `this->value` does not point to any object at all.

Pointer arithmetic is only defined for pointers that point to objects, so by omission this has undefined behavior.

Starting with C++20 this particular source of undefined behavior will be eliminated and compilers currently most likely all behave as one would expect for this.

---

More seriously though, you *never* create objects in the storage location at all. So as soon as you are going to try to access the objects through a `Object*` pointer you will have UB, because C++ requires creation of objects before they can be used. Objects can be created only via a `new` expression, as temporaries, or in a variable definition. (Or implicitly in C++20.)

In your particular case this issue occurs when you call `toString` in the destructor which calls

```
(this -> value + iterator) -> toString()
```

There is no `Object` object created at `this->value+iterator` via a `new` expression, so `this->value+iterator` cannot be pointing to any `Object` object, which means that you are not allowed to call a member function of `Object` on it.

Because `Object` isn't a so-called *implicit-lifetime type* this UB will still be present for C++20 as well.

---

Furthermore, `memmove` between two objects, even if you create the objects first with a placement-`new`, only has defined behavior if the types of the objects are *trivially-copyable*, which your type `Object` is not because it has all copy and move operations deleted.

---

Then, should you fix all of the above issues, there remains a design flaw regarding `realloc`. `realloc` may require copying memory to a new allocation, but that copying does not create objects in the new memory location either. Therefore you would need to copy/move the objects individually. But copying/moving them is impossible if they are non-movable (i.e. have deleted copy and move operations).

Therefore an array implementation such as you want here can only work if you fix the maximum capacity at construction.

---

It is supposed to be impossible to relocate non-movable types from one storage location to another. That is the whole point of having such types. You can only create such types in place with a placement-`new`, but then you can never copy/move them to another storage location.

---

Also note that because of the first issue I mentioned, it is impossible to implement `std::vector` and similar types portable in user code before C++20. (Although, as I wrote, generally pointer arithmetic on allocated storage does work on compilers. The standard just doesn't guarantee it.)

---

There are also more minor issues, such as not checking the return values of `malloc` and `realloc` for failure and missing includes, e.g. `#include<stdlib.h>` for `malloc` and `realloc`.

Comment: Just updated the code... The main issue with the program seems to be 1.) the `memmove` (and `memset`?) operations on non-trivially-copyable objects, 2.) accessing the `this -> value` pointer when no object has been emplaced in it, and 3.) using pointer arithmetic on the `malloc` & `realloc`ed-only pointer, right?

Comment: @Lapys Yes, and then there is a design flaw inherent to having an array-like container of arbitrary size for non-movable types, see my last edit of the answer.

Comment: That should be as plain-sailing as renaming `ObjectArray` to `ObjectVector` I'm guessing. Alright then, let me ask this: how would you resolve these issues (or it is impossible in C++)?

Comment: @Lapys `new[]` and `delete[]` won't work if you want to copy over already created objects. You need to use individual placement-`new`s per object, but as I said this is technically UB before C++20 due to required pointer arithmetic. If you use a pointer indirection, then you end up with practically `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>>`, except that, as I explained above, technically cannot implement it before C++20.

Comment: @Lapys I would use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>>` and be done with it. You can reimplement it yourself in C++20 and that implementation will also work on pre-C++20 compilers, even if the C++ standard doesn't guarantee it, but there isn't really any reason to.

Comment: You have a point there, at least the addresses of objects are (normally) copy-able and move-able. It was fun experimenting, though... Thanks @walnut.